# Pattern of a function call

Tags: winapi, assembly

In a win32 application, what are the assembly code patterns of a function call?

For example I have this class member function:

```
void Foo::bar(MyClass* p, int i, int j, CArray<CArray<int,int>,int> &a){
 // Function body
}
```

Comment: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html

Comment: And for member functions, you also have the [thiscall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw(v=vs.100)) convention.